# How do I get Blender to stop renaming Armatures when I export FBX?

Tags: armature, .fbx

I'm converting a collection of .XPS characters to .FBX format.  Part of my pipeline is to rename the Armature to correctly identify the character I'm exporting, as well as its origin.  I realized that, despite me renaming the armatures, when I re-import it into Blender, the armature has just been re-named to "Armature" or "Armature.1", etc.  How do I get Blender to retain the names I give the armatures?

Comment: Which Blender version are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 3.0

Comment: I've just tested this with the [Rain character model](https://studio.blender.org/characters/5f1ed640e9115ed35ea4b3fb/v2/) and it retains the name after exporting to .fbx and reimporting in Blender 3.0 and more recent versions. Just to be sure, have you double-checked that you are exporting the right object?

Comment: Yes, it's exporting the correct object.  I can re-import it into Blender after I export it without any trouble, except for the name change.